# Removing the About link from maven site

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm using mvn site to generate my site's documentation. For the most part, I'm satisfied with the default site, but I'd like to remove the "About" link from the left hand menu bar and just have the default page be the "Project Information" page. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using that plugin at all and just used the maven-site-plugin. Maven 3 has a reportPlugins configuration section of the maven pom that lets you specified which reports you want to show up http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html

org.apache.maven.plugins
    maven-site-plugin
    3.0
    
        
             
                  org.codehaus.mojo
                  cobertura-maven-plugin

I also provided my own index.apt (in src/site/apt) file to customize the index page text.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you bothered giving details. The point of posting a question is that the answer is later available to others who face the same challenge. -1.

Comment: @OmriSpector you are right. I have made an edit to the post and will update in a little bit with more details.

Comment: @OmriSpector Details added

Answer (score 2):

Here only the 'About' report is still included. All other standard reports are removed.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>

    <!--  Add the Maven project information reports  -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
          <reports>
            <report>index</report>
            <!--
            <report>dependencies</report>
            <report>project-team</report>
            <report>mailing-list</report>
            <report>cim</report>
            <report>issue-tracking</report>
            <report>license</report>
            <report>scm</report>
             -->
          </reports>
        </reportSet>
      </reportSets>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify the source and comment it out or add a css selector for it, or you can include a JS library like jQuery and remove it when the page loads via something like:

```
$(function () {
   // untested
   $('#navcolumn h5:contains("Maven")').hide(); // hide the header
   $('#navcolumn h5:contains("Maven") + ul ').hide(); // hide the ul
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. But what if I wanted to get more advanced like they do at the maven site http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/. I looked at their site.xml and vm template file, but couldn't seem to figure out how they were getting things in there like the "Maven Projects" section. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've always found it quite annoying. The 'About' section is redundant, and more important, cause the 'Project Information' menu is expanded by default when you visit the site. Since I didn't found any solution on the web, I had to figure it out myself.

With the following workaround, the 'About' item under the 'Project Information' menu will completely disappear from the site. Just add this to the `site.xml` file:

```xml
...
<body>
        <head>
            <![CDATA[
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                var linkAbout = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "About"; });
                var projectInformationMenu = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Project Information"; });
                linkAbout.hide();
                if (!projectInformationMenu.parent().hasClass('active')) {
                    projectInformationMenu.parent().children('ul').hide();
                    projectInformationMenu.children('span').removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-right');
                }
            });
            </script>
        ]]>
        </head>
...
</body>
```